# Multiplying values within ArcPy update cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

This code is meant to apply an update cursor to a field called "New_Sq_Mile" when I am populating the field with the area of the polygons. Unfortunately the units are in meters and I need to do a calculation to change those values to miles before they are updated into the table. Here is what I have so far.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(FinalErase, ["SHAPE@AREA", "New_Sq_Mile"])

for row in cursor:
    row[1] = row[0]
    update.row

del row
del cursor
```

Is there a way I can do a calculation in the for loop such as

```
row[1] = row[0]/1606.344
```

Comment: Btw: 1 square meter is not 1/1606,344 square mile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the newer Data Access module Cursors, for example [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). They are alot faster. In your case like this:

```
import arcpy
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FinalErase,["SHAPE@AREA","New_Sq_Mile"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1]=row[0]/1606.344
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I am a student and did not realize there was a difference between cursors and data access module cursors.